# how to fix the jquery error unexpected token error

Tags: php, jquery

I've tried many things and there's no way, always appears this error I tried to use only one option to see if passed, changed the call of jquery, but not.

> Syntax Error: unexpected token <

I looked in various places on the internet about this error, but could not solve or understand why it is happening. On my pc using EasyPHP works perfectly, but when I put online does not work.

```
$(document).on('click','.add_space', function(){

    var id = $(this).attr('rel');
    var url = $(this).attr('rev');
    $.ajax({
        url : completeURL(url),
        type : 'POST',
        dataType : 'html',
        data:{id:id},
        success:function(data)
        {
            $('.form').html($(data).find('.form').html());
        },
        complete: function()
        {
            FormWizard.init();
            PluginPickers.init();
            Metronic.init();
            Layout.init();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Try doing `data: JSON.stringify({id:id}),`

Comment: what will be the completeURL(url)?

Comment: post completeURL code

Comment: The error message doesn't look like it's related to the code provided; check the actual response from the call via the browser's network tab.

Comment: You are passing parameter into the function `completeURL(url)` while in actual function can't seems any parameter passing. `complete: function()`

Comment: @mayank dudakiya 1) completeURL() and complete: are not the same function. The second one isn't even a named function, it's a property whose value is an anonymous callback. Check that you understand the syntax in the code above. 2) even if what you were saying made sense, it wouldn't cause the error mentioned in the question

Comment: Suyash, if the code works in one environment but not the other, then the code itself is unlikely to be the problem. Either you made a mistake in deploying to the server, and missed something, or there's some other difference in the environment, e.g. webserver settings or something. But it's hard to have much idea without some more debugging data. Which line of code is actually causing this error? And have you checked things like your network tool to see if the Ajax call is working as expected, returning the expected headers, data, etc?